# Finding a particular solution to a partial differential equation.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am given the equation:
\begin{equation}2 y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=2 x y^{3}-x^{3} y
\end{equation}
And told that from this, it is possible to obtain:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=x y^{2}, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=x^{2} y$$
Can someone explain how these last equations are obtained from the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2 y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=2 x y^{3}-x^{3} y$$
System of characteristic ODEs (Charpit-Lagrange) :
$$\frac{dx}{2y}=\frac{dy}{-x}=\frac{du}{2xy^3-x^3y}$$
A first characteristic equation  from solving $\frac{dx}{2y}=\frac{dy}{-x}$ :
$$x^2+2y^2=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation from :
$$\frac{dx}{2y}=\frac{dy}{-x}=\frac{du}{2xy^3-x^3y}=\frac{xy^2dx+x^2ydy-du}{xy^2(2y)+x^2y(-x)-(2xy^3-x^3y)}=\frac{xy^2dx+x^2ydy-du}{0}$$
$$xy^2dx+x^2ydy-du=0\quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=xy^2\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=x^2y$$
$$u-\frac12(x^2y^2)=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$u(x,y)=\frac12 x^2y^2+F(x^2+2y^2)$$
with arbitrary function $F$ , to be determined according to some boundary condition.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!